# Facebook like button asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-like

I would like to add a Facebook like button to my asp.net page.

I am using 
[Facebook Like Button plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like)

But unfortunately its not appearing on my page when i run it locally

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like show_faces="false" width="150"></fb:like>
```

or

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpage%2Fto%2Flike&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=150&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:150px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Does anyone have an idea what I might be doign wrong please?

Did I need to set an application first to do this?

Thanks

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Did I need to set an application first to do this?` YES

you are using XFBML , so you need Facebook javascript SDK and that requires app ID.

Comment: thank you for replying. what if i use the iframe approach? it also does not appear

Comment: @C. Regenerate iframe [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like)